# Import module from different project in Overture

Tags: vdm++

When I import one module from another in Overture all is quite straightforward. However, I can't work out how to import a module from another project. What I do is:

- create project P1
- create module A in P1
- create project P2
- specify P1 as a reference in P2
- create module B in P2
- in module B import A

In module B the system flags the error 'No such module as A'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid there is no linking between projects in Overture currently, though you're right that this would be a sensible thing to have and would improve the modularity of specifications. So at the moment, all of your specification files have to live in the same project.

Comment: Thanks for that. I note that when you create a project from the wizard it asks if you want to include libraries (IO, MATH, etc). Is it possible to create my own library and include that in another project?

Comment: All that happens when you include standard libraries (MATH etc) is that the source of the library is added to the "lib" folder. The best you can do is create a separate project with your library module, and then create a "lib" folder (if there isn't already one) where you want to use the library, and then "Import" the library module into lib using the "copy as link" tickbox. That then means that all the users of your library will see updates without you having to re-copy the file. I've just tried this in the latest build, and it does work as expected.